# recovering data from a broken harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

A few days ago my (8 year old) external hard drive died. I free it from the casing and connected it to my PC.

The Computer manager recognizes that the is a disk but its unknown and uninitialized and initialziing it doesn´t work. I tried Minitools for MBR rebuilding and/or recovery but those dont even show the disc.

In its last moments it showed some windows errors that file xy hasnt been written yet and that the writing is delayed.

Comment: **If you wanted the data off the drive you shouldn't have initialzed it.**

Answer (score 0):

I recently used Recuva from Piriform to recover data from old drives.

I did format the drive using a quick format previously and run a full (and very long) recovery process using the application but got a good result back from the application. You can find the application here: https://www.piriform.com/recuva

Comment: worth a try but it did not recognise the disk much like minitools